# Grails 2.3.2/IntelliJ - NullPointerException in GrailsUnitTestMixin shutdownApplicationContext

Tags: grails, spock

After upgrading an application from Grails v2.2.2 to v2.3.2, the controller unit tests run as JUnit Tests in IntelliJIDEA 12 were failing with the exception below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin.shutdownApplicationContext(GrailsUnitTestMixin.groovy:266)
```

Debug shows that the GrailsUnitTestMixin.shutdownApplicationContext() method was invoked twice, thus throwing the exception on the second call.

Note that Spock is used for the unit test and the unit test class extends spock.lang.Specification.

Also, running the test as grails app is successful.

Any inputs on this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the unit test is run from IntelliJ 12. Running the test as grails app has is executed successfully. Only when the test is run as JUnit that it fails as reported above.

Comment: Have you deleted spock plugin from buildconfig?

Comment: @xat: yes done that as part of grails upgrade. As I've mentioned in the comments in the answer below, I think this is more of an environment setup problem. But will post the resolution here in case we got it solved in the "problematic" machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the same issue but I had some issues when upgrading from Grails 2.2 to 2.3 on INTELLIJ 12. I upgraded to the EAP of 13 and it solved my issues.

Here is a forum topic about some migration issues. Perhaps the troubleshooting suggested by these users can help.

[Relevant Thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-0-RC1-and-IntelliJ-IDEA-quot-IDEA-hook-Grails-not-found-quot-td4647657.html)

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply. At the moment, the issue I reported may have something to do more with environment setup as a whole rather than an entirely IntelliJ problem. The basis for that is because we got two boxes now upgraded to Grails 2.3.2, and both using intelliJ 12.1.6, but the problem appears only on one of the machines.

Comment: That is an interesting scenario! I would love to hear how you solve it since I am in the process of upgrading Java stacks on webservers. I have also had the issue where a previous installation of the Java SDK was interfering with upgrading Grails.